# Fantasy book with a girl with an arrow tattoo on her wrist

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in the early 2000s but the book could be from the late 90s. It takes place in a fictional place.

A girl goes out on an adventure to find herself and learns she has powers. What I remember the most is her having an arrow tattoo and her love interest having a bow. It could be part a series. I don't have any more information.

Comment: To clarify, this story was not set on earth, correct? Also did her love interest have a bow tattoo or an actual bow?

Comment: Can you offer any additional info? When you say "fictional place", do you mean medieval, space, alternate world or what? What powers did she gain? Was her love interest male or female?

Comment: Was it a historical novel by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Did a search and found Devil May Cry (Dark-Hunter #12):
http://www.oldlibrary.net/fiction/u2998_22.html

"But what he found fascinating, and the main reason he'd captured her, was that she had a small bow and arrow tattoo on her wrist."

Comment: Seems very unlikely given said girl has her throat ripped out in the part you linked...

Comment: In Sherrilyn Kenyon's Dark-Hunter series, every Dark-Hunter, male and female, has a bow and arrow tattoo symbolizing, among other things, their allegiance to Artemis.  [That is the one place on their body where they are vulnerable, similar to Achilles' heel.  They have other exploitable vulnerabilities as well.]  Dark-Hunters are not exclusively male; many are female.  Here's a link to a list of every Dark-Hunter book (there are 27 so far):     <https://www.goodreads.com/series/83614-dark-hunter>